# I am trying to pass an DMA array and its size as an argument but it is giving an error

Tags: c++, error-handling

I am trying to pass a dynamic memory allocated array and its size to a function 'sum' but it is giving error of permissive what should I do?

```
 #include<conio.h>
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
     int sum(int n[], int *m)
      {
       for(int z=0;z<*m;z++)
      {
        cout<<"\n the output is = "<<n[z]<<"\n";
      }
       }

     int main()
        {

     int *n,*m,a; //declaration is done here**strong text**
     cout<<"enter the size of array = ";
      m=new int;             
      cin>>*m;
      n=new int[*m];
      for(int i=0;i<*m;i++)
       {
          cout<<"\n enter the "<<i+1<<" array = ";
          cin>>n[i];
                cout<<"\n";
        }
         /* for(int z=0;z<*m;z++)
       {
          cout<<"\n the output is = "<<n[z]<<"\n";
        }*/
      int sum(n,&m);//here "m" is an pointer and I am trying to pass int in a function with an array 
      return 0;
      }
```

Comment: `m` is an `int *`, so `&m` is the adress of a pointer, an `int**`, too much. Why not simply using `int m` ?

Comment: Besides `sum` should return an `int` and the line `int sum(n, m);` in main() is not clear. Sorry, but there are many errors in your code

Comment: yes I know there are many errors in my code because I am new @Damien.What should I do exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should, probably, look like the following (Linux Ubuntu + gcc):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int sum(int n[], int m)
{
  int s=0;
  for(int z=0; z<m; z++)
  {
    cout<<"\n array["<<z<<"]= "<<n[z]<<"\n";
    s+=n[z];
   }
   return s;
}

int main()
{
  int *n,m;
  cout<<"enter the size of array = ";             
  cin>>m;
  n=new int[m];
  for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
  {
    cout<<"\n enter array["<<i+1<<"] value = ";
    cin>>n[i];
    cout<<"\n";
  }
  int s = sum(n, m);
  cout<<"s="<<s<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

There is no use allocating the size of the array *m* dynamically. It is an ordinary *int* variable and can be initialized as

```
cin>>m;
```

You may also write the *sum* prototype in the form

```
int sum(int * n, int m)
```

It is another way of passing a 1-dimensional array as a function parameter.

Speaking frankly, these questions are the very basics of the language. 
You should, probably, read something like
[Dynamic memory allocation/dynamic arrays](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/)
about dynamic memory allocation and dynamic arrays and
[Simple cases of std::cin usage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin)
about the simplest cases of std::cin usage in C++.